# Web App and MVC app showing different authentication message

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am trying to authenticate my application with Azure AD. The application is already registered with Azure AD. The legacy application is a ASP.NET Web App. Initially, I was having issues make it work. I found a sample of MVC app and create a new sample app.

When the new app. opens and hits Azure AD, it is showing message:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jhqE.png

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jhqE.png]

I replaced the Startup.cs in the legacy application to Owin Startup.cs and added the same code. When this app hits Azure AD, it is directly showing "Access is denied" error.

I want to know whether Admin consent should solve problem for both or anything else is required for the legacy app.

Comment: Can you please share the code of `Startup.cs` to understand the issue better?

Answer (score 0):

If i can answer more precisely to your question, i tried repro in my local using Asp .net mvc And Created demo application with Azure AD which gave me access to login successfully .

Below are the steps which i followed

Login into AzurePortal >Azure Active Directory> Create a New Tenant >Switch To your Created Tenant.

[image]

from tenant go to > Manage > App registration > new registration.

[image]

And during registration make sure to provide the local host as per your application.

[image]

After Register Go to > Overview > Check and copy all the credentials like client ID, tenant id, Redirect URL as below:

[image]

You just need to click on authentication option from manage then scroll down to get ID TOKEN Check box. And to use single tenant Mark as yes and save it.

[image]

After Successfully done with azure ad tenant create ,app register and Authentication.

From visual studio project from root of your folder download the below `nuget Packages`:**Microsoft.AspNetCore.authentication.AzureAD** **& Microsoft. Identity. Web**
[image]

Then go to `startup.cs` file and update under the configuration services as below:

```
public  void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

{

**services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection(****"AzureAd"****));**

services.AddControllersWithViews();

}
```

click on **`appsetting.json`** file and update the below code as per your credential which created before in Portal>Azure AD> App register>overview.

```
{

"AzureAd": {

"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",

"Domain": " ******.onmicrosoft.com",

"ClientId": "*****",

"TenantId": "*****",

"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"

},
```

[image]

And in startup.cs file update the authentication as below:

```
**app.UseAuthentication();**

app.UseAuthorization();
```

[image]

In homecontroler.cs file Add a attribute called **[Authorize]** :

[image]

After that Run the application Which will redirect to MS sign-on page with access.
[image]

For further details Please refer the below the links:

.[AAD Authentication error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/137574/azure-active-directory-authentication-error-owin.html)

. [Add sign-in to Microsoft to an ASP.NET web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp#register-your-application)